# Fix user login changing to root

Tags: ssh, login, root

I have a VM here running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64) and we was given access to it through a user let's call it `userx` so every time we login to this VM through `ssh` like:

```
ssh -p 22 userx@1.2.3.4
```

It automatically changes the user to **root** so it enters in the machine as:

```
root@machinename:~#
```

And if I run the `pwd` it shows that I am in the `userx` folder `/home/userx`. And if I run `su userx` it log in as root again.

So how do I change that so when logging in with `userx` I actually get logged in as `userx` like `userx@machinename:~#` ?

**Edit** as requested in comments:

```
root@machinename:~# grep userx /etc/passwd
userx:x:0:0:somename,,,:/home/userx:/bin/bash
```

I changed the value of `somename` to keep the privacy. I take that it is the group right?

```
root@machinename:~# ls -l /home
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 10 1000 userx 4096 Nov  8 11:10 userx
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `grep userx /etc/passwd` and `ls -l /home`

Comment: @Panther done as requested. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is "userx" is root. Root is identified by UID of 0 as shown in /etc/passwd

```
userx:x:0:0:somename,,,:/home/userx:/bin/bash
```

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/ for understanding the output.

So, what you can do, although it is moderately invasive, do all this from a root shell !!!

In your case you will need to manually edit `etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups`

```
nano /etc/passwd
```

edit the userx line

```
userx:x:1000:1000:somename,,,:/home/userx:/bin/bash
```

Then /etc/groups

At least

```
userx:x:1000:
```

While you are there, you can add userx as needed to other groups. Add userx at the end of the line, comma separated if needed (posted this list from a desktop install). You may add yourself to other groups as needed (www-data ?)

```
adm:x:4:syslog,userx
cdrom:x:24:userx
sudo:x:27:userx
dip:x:30:userx
plugdev:x:46:userx
lpadmin:x:118:userx
userx:x:1000:
sambashare:x:128:userx
```

Then setup ssh (if needed)

```
cp -R /root/.ssh /home/userx
chown -R userx:userx /home/userx
```

BEFORE YOU EXIT THE ROOT SHELL , from your client, test ssh and sudo

```
ssh userx@1.2.3.4 #you do not need to specify the port if it is the default
```

Now assuming you can long in via ssh, test sudo

```
sudo -i
```

As long as you can log in via ssh and obtain a root shell you are good to go.

If you have a problem you will need to post back, we may need to configure ssh and / or sudo

Comment: When I run `usermod -l root userx` it says `usermod: user 'root' already exists` ignore and keep going or do I have to do something else?

Comment: I executed the command you updated `usermod -u 1000 userx` and it returns `usermod: user userx is currently used by process 1` is it a problem?

Comment: I will check the ssh and sudo of course, when I get to that part :)

Comment: Yes, Just did it, and tested every thing and it is working fine!! Thank you!! I will mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

You user `userx` has the ID and Group ID 0, that means it become automatically a root user. You may have to create a user with different ID, best practice are starting from 1000 as previous ID are supposed to be reserved for the system accounts.

userx:x:**0**:**0**:somename,,,:/home/userx:/bin/bash

The syntax to change a user ID is:

```
usermod -u UID userx
```

By example

```
usermod -u 1000 userx
```

And to change the primary group

```
usermod -g groupx userx
```

By example, for having the user to be member of a group with the same same (default behavior in Linux).

```
groupadd userx # < Command useless for you as group userx already exists
usermod -g userx userx
```

Comment: Yep, that's an old trick to backdoor systems.  Used to change the nobody built-in user to a login shell and 0:0 for an obvious but not TOO obvious backdoor people usually overlook.

Comment: great answer, but we still need to make sure both ssh and sudo are working.

Comment: Hi olivierb2, thanks for your answer and explanation. I will upvote it. I will try the Panther's answer though, it is more complete (ssh/sudo test)

Comment: Did not work (read comments above) "usermod -u 1000 userx and it returns usermod: user userx is currently used by process 1" so will probably not work with 'su root' or from recovery mode due to userx == root == UID 0 but I am not sure.

Comment: You should do my command by connecting with root account directly from the VM console (not over ssh). If it's not feasible, you may have temporarily allow root from ssh and enable root password.

Comment: After the last update from Phanter, everything worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work as userx == root == UID 0 `usermod: user userx is currently used by process 1` is the error logged into console as root and via ssh both.

Comment: Same error in recovery mode as well `usermod: user userx is currently used by process 1`